# Get value and display according to user selection on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The question is how to get value from user input from form and calculate the value and display it on selection by radio box. User can select to submit the selection or to clear the form.

This is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <form name="frm">
        <table bordercolor="black" width="500">
            <td colspan="4" align="center"><b>TBB1033/TCB1033 Coursework Marks Calculator</br></b>

                </br>Please enter marks for the following coursework components.</br>The mark for each component is between 0 and 100 inclusive.</br>
                </br>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Test 1:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="test1">
                        </th>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </br>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Test 2:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="test2">
                        </th>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </br>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Assignment:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="assignment">
                        </th>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </br>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Quiz:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="quiz">
                        </th>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </br>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Lab Work:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="labwork">
                        </th>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </br>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="a" checked="checked">Coursework Marks</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="a">Coursework Grade</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="calculate()" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Result:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text" type="text" name="total" value="0" id="total">
                        </th>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
function calculate() {
    var a = document.getElementById("test1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("test2").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("assignment").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("quiz").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("labwork").value;
    var document.getElementById("total").value  =  parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c) + parseInt(d + parseInt(e);
}

function clear() {
    document.frm.getElementById("test1").value = '';
    document.frm.getElementById("test2").value = '';
    document.frm.getElementById("assignment").value = '';
    document.frm.getElementById("quiz").value = '';
    document.frm.getElementById("labwork").value = '';
}
```

The result show be as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8aBQ.jpg
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4sFz.jpg

Comment: Based on what are calculating `coursework grade`??

Comment: Coursework grade will be calculated as such if the result 90-100, the grade will be A, if 80-90 the grade will be B, and so on. It will be calculated based on OnClick() by user selection on the selection radio box and will display in the result box according to user selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    function calculate() {
    var a = document.getElementById("test1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("test2").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("assignment").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("quiz").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("labwork").value;
    document.getElementById("total").value  =  (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c) + parseInt(d) + parseInt(e));
}

function cclear() {
    document.getElementById("test1").value = '';
    document.getElementById("test2").value = '';
    document.getElementById("assignment").value = '';
    document.getElementById("quiz").value = '';
    document.getElementById("labwork").value = '';
}
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RLZd8/5/)

For clearing the form you can use `type="reset"` it will clear the form

```
<input type="reset">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RLZd8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Replace:

```
var document.getElementById("total").value  =  parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c) +
                                               parseInt(d + parseInt(e);
```

by:

```
 document.getElementById("total").value  =  parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c) + 
                                            parseInt(d + parseInt(e);
```